# Detect Network Connection in Visual studio Xamarin crash android app

Tags: android, xamarin, crash, internet-connection

In my first Xamarin android app i stuck with another one problem.
When I try to check connection app is crashed.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(ConnectivityService);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo;
if (netInfo.IsConnected)
{
  pictureSubText.Text = "Internet OK";
}
else
{
  pictureSubText.Text = "No Internet";
}
```

When it's come to if(netInfo.IsConnected), App crashes and run again.
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and INTERNET are checked in manifest.
I'll be appreciated for any help.

***--UPDATED--***

Seems code I use are available only for API 21+
So another question - is it possible to check internet connection in API less than 21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link useful for you,

Add permissions also

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/276931#Comment_276931